# Deleting feature class after importing into feature dataset?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, feature-class

Here are my actions so far:

1. create gdb
2. import feature classes
3. create new feature dataset
4. import feature classes

So now I have my feature datasets with all my layers as well as the original feature classes. Is it safe to delete the duplicate feature classes?

Comment: So you have duplicate features in your gdb, one set outside a feature dataset, one set in? You can delete the duplicates, but it's always good to have a backup. But why didn't you create the feature dataset first, and import directly to that? Also, you may want to add a tag indicating which version of (presumably) ArcGIS you're using, or whatever software if different.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be extra safe, check to make sure all of the original and copied feature classes have identical attributes and geometry before you delete the originals. Here is a simple Python utility to do that. You can also configure the tool to produce a csv report on the differences.

```py
import arcpy, os

# The original and the duplicate workspaces   
ws1 = r'C:\temp\test1.gdb'
ws2 = r'C:\temp\test2.gdb'

arcpy.env.workspace = ws1

fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

bad_list = []
for fc in fcs:
    original =  os.path.join(ws1, fc) # Not really necessary, except for symmetry
    copy =      os.path.join(ws2, fc)
    compare_result = arcpy.FeatureCompare_management(original, copy, "OBJECTID")
    if compare_result.getOutput(1) == 'false':
        bad_list.append(fc)

if len(bad_list) > 0:
    print "%s fc's are not identical" % len(bad_list)
    print bad_list

else:
    print "All of the fc's are identical"
```